# The size of a variable is 12 bytes, but why the address of the variable shows me that it took 15 bytes?

Tags: c

I used the follow the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a;
  int b[3];
  printf("%d \n", sizeof(b));
  printf("%p \n", &a);
  printf("%p \n", &b);

  return 0;
}
```

The size of int b[3] is 12. But I got the address of a is 000000000061FE1F, and the address of b is 000000000061FE10. The difference between the two addresses is 15 but not 12.

When I define b[3] as char b[3]. It doesn't have such a problem. The char size of b[3] is 3.  I got the address of a is 000000000061FE1F, and the address of b is 000000000061FE1C. The difference between the two addresses is 3.

One more question: I define a first, the address of a should be smaller than b. why here are b bigger than a?

Comment: Where did you read that the two variables need to be right next to each other in memory or in any given order? There are no such guarantees/requirements.

Comment: It's likely a combination of the local variables being aligned with some word boundary (12+1 ->16, whereas before it was 3+1 -> 4), with a slight misunderstanding of how that memory is packed. The order of the addresses/memory allocation does not necessarily occur in order of the declaration in the code, the compiler can optimize the allocations.

Comment: Nor in a particular order. That is only guaranteed to `struct` members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to something called alignment of variable, suppose `sizeof(int) = 4` and `a = 0` and  `b[0] = 0; b[1] = 0; b[2] = 0;` and the width of **the memory = 4** and the stack pointer is descending not ascending then look at the next image:

[image]

so any `int` variable should be stored at only the addresses which are multiples of **4** which is the width of the memory and `char` variable can be stored at place in the memory which are multiples of **1**.

so what happens is when you wrote :

```
char a;
int b[3];
```

this made `a` created in the stack in the begging of place which is a multiple of **4**. and for **b** its start address should be stored in address which is multiple of **4** and the first place that matches this condition is at address `&a - 0x04`
so the start address of `b` will be **0x0018**. this something done by the compiler to make MCU fetch values from the memory faster.

in your case, the compiler optimizes the placement of `int` variable by placing it in addresses which are multiple of **16**. so if **the address of a is 000000000061FE1F**, **then address of b = `&a - 0x0F` = 000000000061FE10**.

this is just some compiler optimization to make you MCU faster when fetching values from the memory and there will be a place in the memory which is padded and not use.

### how to solve it

just declare the variable with variable attribute `aligned`.

refer to [6.34.1 Common Variable Attributes (GCC docs)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) where it states that:

> **aligned**
>
> **aligned (alignment)**
>
> The aligned attribute specifies a minimum alignment for the variable
> or structure field, measured in bytes. When specified, alignment must
> be an integer constant power of 2. Specifying no alignment argument
> implies the maximum alignment for the target, which is often, but by
> no means always, 8 or 16 bytes.
>
> For example, the declaration:
>
> `int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;`

which means that if you write:

```
int x __attribute__ ((aligned (1))) = 0;
```

it makes the variable called `x` be stored in memory location which are multiples of **1**.

so the above image becomes:

[image]

so I edited your code according to GCC and this is the edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a = 0;
  int b[3] __attribute__ ((aligned (1))) = {0};
  printf("%p \n", &a);
  printf("%p \n", &b);
  printf("%d \n", sizeof(b));

  return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
00000018eabffbef
00000018eabffbe3
12
```

where the difference between the 2 addresses is **12**.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, the compiler can optimize memory areas allocated to variables.

What this shows however is about memory aligment. A char is one byte and thus does not need to be aligned to 2, 4, or 8 bytes unlike (u)int16_t, (u)int32_t, or (u)int64_t.

Play around within a structure definition, you will be surprised!